# is_object with concatenate doesn't work normal?

Tags: php

Here is the problem:

1. When i write this

   ```
   echo is_object($person->getCompany()) ? $person->getCompany()->getName() : 'test';
   ```

it returns me "test".

2. But when i write this

   ```
   echo 'Company: ' . PHP_EOL . is_object($person->getCompany()) ? $person->getCompany()->getName() : 'test';
   ```

it returns me error

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getName()
>   on string

So same code, same variables, but first time it execute right part (it's not an object), next time execute left part ?

Comment: In the second case it's taking everything before the `?` as being the condition, you need to use brackets to make sure you just take the `is_object()` as the condition.

Comment: I would put `(....)` around the whole tenary operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this fails it because of the order the expression is parsed. Try using parentheses around your ternary operator:

```
echo 'Company: ' . 
     PHP_EOL . 
     (is_object($person->getCompany()) ? $person->getCompany()->getName() : 'test');
```

Comment: Thank u dude, but @Schleis was first and i will accepct his answer :)

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm To be fair, I actually posted my answer six seconds before him. But it is fine. His answer is better.

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm This answer seems better because it shows how to fix the problem.

Comment: Accept your argument and that answer :)

Answer (score 5):

In the second case, your ternary is being evaluated differently.

PHP is checking to see if `'Company: ' . PHP_EOL . is_object($person->getCompany())` is TRUE or FALSE not the `is_object`.  The `is_object` result gets appended to your string and since non-empty strings are always true, the first part of your ternary gets evaluated resulting in your error.